# Trouble solving "No module named 'encodings'" issue with mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, rhel, certbot

EDIT: I solved it and will update soon. Seems to have helped to compile mod_wsgi from source, and there were other things that also helped.

First of all, I realize that this is a common problem but I think the issue is a mixture of some solutions not working and myself not being an expert on web servers and being a first-time deployer of a Django project, so I probably missed something. Just a nudge in the right direction would be very helpful.

The issue mainly surrounds the Apache package mod_wsgi which facilitates the hosting of the Django application in question here. System-wide installation on my Red Hat Linux Enterprise (7) leads to this error (work server to which I have sudo access). I include anonymized system and error output below. Some important notes:

- The Django project runs in a virtualenv on /var/www.
- Both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 are running on the system.
- Both mod_wsgi compiled for Python 2 and the newest mod_wsgi (installed with yum; python3-mod_wsgi.x86_64; including httpd-devel required for APXS) are on the system:

```
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi_python3.so
```

- The former was first loaded, skipping the second, so I uncommented the relevant line in /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-wsgi.conf, after which the warning disappeared. In /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-wsgi-python3.conf, I have:

```
<IfModule !wsgi_module>
    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi_python3.so
</IfModule>
```

(EDIT: I have now uncommented the tag lines but there seems to be no difference.)

- A former iteration (demo) of the project running on Python 2 was running on the server, which was last updated in 2019 (I think). I copied and adapted its configuration file for the current (Python 3) project. Its full contents are at the end of the post.

The Apache error output includes:

```
...
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.639052 2022] [core:notice] [pid 8125] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.640505 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8199] mod_wsgi (pid=8199): Python home /var/www/myproject/env.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.640547 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8199] mod_wsgi (pid=8199): Initializing Python.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.640758 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8200] mod_wsgi (pid=8200): Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.640796 2022] [wsgi:warn] [pid 8200] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=8200): Unable to stat Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
...
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

- The supplied path exists and is to my knowledge correct.
- I used the system-wide Python 3.6 to create the virtualenv (virtualenv -p python3 env; python3.6 bin is included in the env).
- Access permissions seem fine. The project folder belongs to myself and to the same working group that the demo belongs to. I cannot set it to www-data as there is no actual group with this name. However, the log/ directory inside the demo belongs to the group "apache", so I set it as the same in my project. I made sure to "chmod g+s myproject-folder" and, for safety, "chmod o-rwx myproject-folder".

EDIT: I also checked permissions in directories inside the project folders and compared them to those of the demo project. I changed one or two minor things but there was no effect.

Since the demo app has the same name as the main app inside the new Django project, I decided to remove the demo's config file to be safe (it's not really needed anymore).

Assuming that the demo config file was correct (after all, it was working), I have changed only the relevant paths. In the main Apache config file (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf), DocumentRoot is "/var/www/html". It is not set anywhere in the project configs.

Based on online advice, I've tried the following:

- Deleted the virtualenv and reinstalled all requirements.
- Made sure of my paths in Apache project conf file (see below).

Apache thinks it's running, but it doesn't serve the domain.

```
$ apachectl configtest / apachectl --help / httpd -t (and some others)
AH00526: Syntax error on line 163 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
SSLCACertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.web.site/fullchain.pem' does not exist or is empty
```

The specific certificate file does exist and is not empty. EDIT: It was outdated but I managed to update using proxy settings in Bash:

```
$ sudo bash
# https_proxy=http://proxy.company.xx.xx:0000 certbot
```

and similarly, with https.

I managed to get the server running for a while last night but I can't replicate the situation yet. Basically it came down to: (1) moving and adding various .conf files to and from /etc/httpd/conf.d and (2) adding a new .conf file containing just the header from the deb.conf file that was removed (based on a suggestion from an ex-colleague):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName my.web.host
   Redirect permanent /otherproject/ https://web.host.xx/otherproject/
   Redirect permanent /admin/ https://my.web.host/admin/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =my.web.host
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

This at some point seemed to have the desired effect but now something is broken again.

I have been reading through the following file meant to help test your mod_wsgi installation: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html

For now, I can't check my Apache build information because of the aforementioned syntax error.

Following the page, these are the statically loaded modules:

```
$ httpd -l

Compiled in modules:
    core.c
    mod_so.c
    http_core.c
```

I could determine that the value in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, whether it is set or not, does not change anything, so I left it as is.

httpd -M (list of static and shared modules) leads to the same syntax error.

Next, I am not sure how to test the various different WSGI scripts in the document. Nothing seems to happen if I just run the script in my virtualenv. But I'm sure I'm missing something.

The main Apache configuration file includes all *.confs by default. Below is the project configuration file including error_log as from today.

EDIT: It has been suggested that I should try to disable SELinux temporarily. Setting setenforce to 0 changes the "current mode" to "permissive" instead of "enforcing". This however seems to have no effect. Sestatus output:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

If you've read this far, many thanks for your time!

Here is my main httpd.conf file.

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

TraceEnable off
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
RewriteEngine On
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Here is the anonymized project conf file.

```
###<VirtualHost *:*>
#    WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
    ServerName my.server.name
    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject user=apache group=apache threads=3 processes=1 inactivity-timeout=86400 display-name=myproject python-home=/var/www/myproject/env python-path=/var/www/myproject/myproject/project home=/var/www/myproject/myproject/project
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject/myproject/project/wsgi.py process-group=myproject
    WSGIPythonHome python-home=/var/www/myproject/env
    WSGIPythonPath /var/www/myproject/myproject
    #Since mod_wsgi 4.1.0:
    #WSGIPythonHashSeed random
    # for now, see /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service

    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/myproject-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/myproject-access.log" combined
    LogLevel info


    <Directory /var/www/myproject/myproject/project>
        WSGIProcessGroup myproject
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
       <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
       </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /myproject/static/ /var/www/myproject/static/
    <Directory /var/www/myproject/static>
      Allow from all
      ExpiresActive on
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 4 hours"
      <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript image/svg+xml application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/x-icon
        #Don't compress content which is already compressed
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(gif|jpe?g|png|swf|woff|woff2) no-gzip dont-vary
        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
                Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
       </IfModule>
    </Directory>

###</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: Including lines from the error log associated with server restart:

```
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.417162 2022] [core:notice] [pid 8125] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.418649 2022] [suexec:notice] [pid 8125] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.419201 2022] [ssl:info] [pid 8125] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.420456 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 8125] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.420481 2022] [ssl:info] [pid 8125] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.6 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.6, Library: OpenSSL/1.0.2k
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.4531 8129/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1366 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.4786 8132/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1310 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.4788 8132/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5057 8132/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:985 ]: Passenger core online, PID 8132

[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5106 8132/T7 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:641 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5106 8132/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1216 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5107 8132/T9 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5107 8132/T9 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5108 8132/Tb Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5108 8132/Tb Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5108 8132/Td Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5108 8132/Td Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5108 8132/Tf Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.5] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5108 8132/Tf Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.5] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5108 8132/Th Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.6] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5108 8132/Th Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.6] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5109 8132/Tj Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.7] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5109 8132/Tj Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.7] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5109 8132/Tl Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.8] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5109 8132/Tl Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.8] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5109 8132/T7 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5109 8132/T7 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5110 8132/Tn Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5110 8132/Tn Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.553124 2022] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 8125] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.553753 2022] [socache_shmcb:info] [pid 8125] AH00830: Shared memory socache initialised
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.553853 2022] [socache_shmcb:info] [pid 8125] AH00830: Shared memory socache initialised
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.553858 2022] [ssl:info] [pid 8125] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.555087 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 8125] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.555104 2022] [ssl:info] [pid 8125] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.6 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.6, Library: OpenSSL/1.0.2k
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.5837 8162/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1366 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.6040 8132/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1295 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.6066 8165/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1310 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.6071 8165/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2022-03-03 23:27:32.6346 8165/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:985 ]: Passenger core online, PID 8165
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.636458 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8199] mod_wsgi (pid=8199): Starting process 'myproject' with uid=48, gid=48 and threads=3.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.639018 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8125] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips Phusion_Passenger/5.3.7 mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.6 confi
gured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.639040 2022] [mpm_prefork:info] [pid 8125] AH00164: Server built: Jan 11 2022 00:03:24
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.639052 2022] [core:notice] [pid 8125] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.640505 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8199] mod_wsgi (pid=8199): Python home /var/www/myproject/env.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.640547 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8199] mod_wsgi (pid=8199): Initializing Python.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.640758 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8200] mod_wsgi (pid=8200): Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.640796 2022] [wsgi:warn] [pid 8200] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=8200): Unable to stat Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.640842 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8200] mod_wsgi (pid=8200): Initializing Python.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.641463 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8203] mod_wsgi (pid=8203): Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.641497 2022] [wsgi:warn] [pid 8203] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=8203): Unable to stat Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.641532 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8203] mod_wsgi (pid=8203): Initializing Python.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.644579 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8209] mod_wsgi (pid=8209): Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.644644 2022] [wsgi:warn] [pid 8209] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=8209): Unable to stat Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.644698 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8209] mod_wsgi (pid=8209): Initializing Python.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.645167 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8204] mod_wsgi (pid=8204): Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.645199 2022] [wsgi:warn] [pid 8204] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=8204): Unable to stat Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.645235 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8204] mod_wsgi (pid=8204): Initializing Python.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.645324 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8205] mod_wsgi (pid=8205): Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.645354 2022] [wsgi:warn] [pid 8205] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=8205): Unable to stat Python home python-home=/var/www/myproject/env. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
[Thu Mar 03 23:27:32.645390 2022] [wsgi:info] [pid 8205] mod_wsgi (pid=8205): Initializing Python.
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

EDIT: error_log as from today.

```
Sat Mar 05 12:13:49.066660 2022] [core:notice] [pid 4907] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Sat Mar 05 12:13:49.067695 2022] [suexec:notice] [pid 4907] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1003 4911/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1366 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1287 4914/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1310 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1289 4914/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1543 4914/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:985 ]: Passenger core online, PID 4914

[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1591 4914/T7 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:641 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1592 4914/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1216 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1592 4914/T9 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1593 4914/T9 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1593 4914/Tb Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1593 4914/Tb Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1593 4914/Td Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1593 4914/Td Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1593 4914/Tf Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.5] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1593 4914/Tf Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.5] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1594 4914/Th Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.6] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1594 4914/Th Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.6] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1594 4914/Tj Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.7] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1594 4914/Tj Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.7] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1595 4914/T7 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1595 4914/T7 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1595 4914/Tn Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1595 4914/Tn Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1595 4914/Tl Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.8] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.1595 4914/Tl Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.8] Shutdown finished
[Sat Mar 05 12:13:49.195551 2022] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4907] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Mar 05 12:13:49.195667 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 4907] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.2223 4944/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1366 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.2440 4947/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1310 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.2442 4947/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.2632 4914/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1295 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:13:49.2694 4947/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:985 ]: Passenger core online, PID 4947
[Sat Mar 05 12:13:49.273445 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4907] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips Phusion_Passenger/5.3.7 mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 05 12:13:49.273476 2022] [core:notice] [pid 4907] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[ E 2022-03-05 12:15:58.5845 4947/T5 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:507 ]: Security update check failed: Couldn't connect to server for https://securitycheck.phusionpassenger.com/v1/check.json (if this error persists check your connection security or try upgrading Passenger) (next check in 24 hours)
[Sat Mar 05 12:18:59.071233 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4907] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0878 4947/T7 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:641 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0886 4947/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1216 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/T9 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/Tj Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.7] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/Tl Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.8] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/T9 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/Tj Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.7] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/Tl Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.8] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/Tc Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/Td Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/Tf Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.5] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/T7 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/Tc Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/T7 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/Td Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/Th Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.6] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0888 4947/Tf Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.5] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0889 4947/Th Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.6] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0889 4947/Tn Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.0889 4947/Tn Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-03-05 12:19:00.1932 4947/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1295 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
```

EDIT: The content of the WSGI script is unchanged from the one already present in Django 2.2:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: please show the beginning of the startup message from Apache in the error.log

Comment: The only log file that seems to be currently updated (since 27 February) is myproject-error.log (in /etc/httpd/logs/ or /var/log/httpd). I found the first lines from yesterday when starting up the server and have updated the OP with it up until the already quoted lines. (I think Passenger core is associated with an unrelated, different project (also not really active anymore).)

Comment: All right, so the reason that error.log didn't show is that Apache wasn't really running (it just thought it did). I experimented with moving various conf files to a temporary directory and then checking if the syntax error still appears (after restarting the server each time). Details are in the OP.

I have updated the OP both with this information as well as the actual error_log log, as well as with another issue I have regarding SELinux.